# How to verify Bingbot? or is the Bingbot broken?

Tags: php, dns, bing, msn, reverse-dns

I just tried to verify the Bingbot and used the rules of this official microsoft blog entry:
http://www.bing.com/community/site_blogs/b/webmaster/archive/2012/08/31/how-to-verify-that-bingbot-is-bingbot.aspx

This technique works most of the time, but in some cases it doesn't: (my or their fault?)

**Works:**
`202.96.51.137` with a reverse DNS check: `gethostbyname(gethostbyaddr(202.96.51.137))` results in `202.96.51.137`

**Wrong result:**
This MSN bot IP: `65.55.213.246` is checked with a reverse DNS check `gethostbyname(gethostbyaddr(65.55.213.246))`
and results in: `msnbot-65-55-213-246.search.msn.com`  (usually they resolve with an ip)

**Another wrong result**
This MSN bot IP: `157.55.33.113` checked with a reverse DNS `gethostbyname(gethostbyaddr("157.55.33.113"))` resolves in `157.55.33.11` (IP D class wrong)

Comment: Just because a crawler claims to be something doesn't mean it **IS** that thing. User agents are trivial to forge, and many stupid paywall systems go purely off the UA string. "Are you googlebot?" "Uh... yes?"  "Welcome, here's all of our protected content!"

Comment: that why i verify the bot with useragent, DNS and Reverse DNS Check...